# SelectKbest, Treeclassifer, small error somewhere :(

Tags: scikit-learn, classification

Doing a course and I am stuck at what I think has to be a small problem.
I wanna find out with SelectKBest what are the most important features(I vary `k` from 2,4,6,8)

I load the data

```
data_dict = pickle.load(open("final_project_dataset.pkl", "r") )
my_dataset = data_dict
data = featureFormat(my_dataset, feature_combo, sort_keys = True)
labels, features = targetFeatureSplit(data)
kbest = SelectKBest(k=2)
train_new= kbest.fit_transform(features,labels)
```

with `get_support` I find out the most important features and then try to use it with my classifer

```
from sklearn import tree 
clf1 = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=2)
test_classifier(clf1, my_dataset, feature_lists2)
```

I used a feature list first with all the features I called combo:

```
feature_combo=['poi','salary','bonus','total_stock_value','long_term_incentive','restricted_stock_deferred','from_this_person_to_poi','shared_receipt_with_poi','newfeature_ratio','total_payments','deferral_payments','loan_advances', 'restricted_stock','director_fees','to_messages','from_messages']
```

After getting the most important ones I created feature lists like :

```
feature_lists2=['salary','bonus']
```

When I run it I get a cryptic error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stephan\Downloads\ud120-projects\final_project\poi_id.py", line 62, in <module>
    train_new= kbest.fit_transform(features,labels)
  File "C:\Users\Stephan\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 429, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "C:\Users\Stephan\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py", line 300, in fit
    self._check_params(X, y)
  File "C:\Users\Stephan\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py", line 405, in _check_params
    % self.k)
ValueError: k should be >=0, <= n_features; got 2.Use k='all' to return all features.
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong ? ( I am a beginner )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear to me. I'm not sure when you are exactly getting this error and you did not supply data to make a reproducible example. However, if you read your error message it states the issue pretty clearly:

> ValueError: k should be >=0, <= n_features; got 2.Use k='all' to return all features.

This means that your `k` parameter in your `SelectKBest()` object was not within appropriate range. Specifically k=2 was greater than n_features, which means that the data you passed into the your `kbest.fit_transform()` call had fewer than 2 columns. Without seeing any data I can't say *why* that is happening, but it is almost surely the source of your error.

Comment: I get the same error: "ValueError: k should be >=0, <= n_features = 1; got 10. Use k='all' to return all features", but I have 29 features and my X = 1 column, while y = 28 columns... Am I misunderstanding something? I don't use fit_transform(), but SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=10) and then fit(X, y)